# locale issue with Chinese characters for JSON Parser

Tags: java, jackson, locale

I am trying to convert object to JSON using JsonUtil.objectToJson. But some Chinese characters(like 扼腕 扼腕) in the object converted as ‘?’ .

```
  String jsonStr = JsonUtil.objectToJson(agreement);
  jsonStr = new String(jsonStr.getBytes(),"UTF-8");
  JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Comment: please add what library is this `JsonUtils` from and what is `agreement`?

Comment: @nullpointer Thanks I got it resolved it. I removed "UTF-8" encoder which was creating problem.